# How do I solve this "NotFoundHttpException" error in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, oop, laravel, frameworks

I'm getting this error, while trying to access a page that I've added in my routes.. 
ex. laravel.com/about-us

here's a sample of my routes code.
I was asked to do the routes in config.php

```html
'about-us' => [
            'controller' => 'page',
            'method' => 'about',
            'enable' => true
        ],
```

and a method like this.

```html
public function about() {
        return view($this->getViewPrefix() . '::page.about');
    }
```

The ful error:

```html
NotFoundHttpException in Application.php line 879:
in Application.php line 879
at Application->abort('404', '', array()) in helpers.php line 21
at abort('404') in helpers.php line 45
at cd_abort('404') in routes.php line 93
at ServiceProvider->{closure}('about-us')
at call_user_func_array(object(Closure), array('param1' => 'about-us')) in Route.php line 155
at Route->runCallable(object(Request)) in Route.php line 130
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 704
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 706
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 671
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 631
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 236
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 50
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 122
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 87
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

I personally don't think it's how I did these things, because one of my colleagues got two of these pages to work, (they only have two) .. 
does this have to do with my installation, or maybe my OS lol.?

Comment: did you find the solution? How did you solve this problem? I am also getting this error, can you please share your answer with me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can write routes in config file. You have to write your routes in this file `app/Http/routes.php` Write these lines

```
Route::get('about-us', [
    'as' => 'aboutUs', 'uses' => 'PagesController@about'
]);
```

Write your controller's name instead of PagesController. You have to make your controller inside this folder `app/Http/Controllers`

Comment: no- don't think so, you can actually. 2 of my colleagues are doing the same thing -- with no problems.. it just happens that I'm having the problem. By the way, these views I've created are from a cloned repository.. maybe that will help.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has the routes.php file to contain all the application related routing. This file will be autoloaded when the application runs.

Therefore, include your routing in this file for best practice.

A "get" routing will be like:

```
Route::get('/about-us', [ 'as' => 'about', 'uses' => 'PagesController@about']);
```

Similarly a 'post' routing:

```
Route::post('/about-us', [ 'as' => 'about', 'uses' => 'PagesController@about']);
```

Remember to name the controller file as "PagesController". Its the proper naming convention.

"@about" is the method in the PagesController that will handle the logic.

For better understanding: [Laravel Routing](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#basic-routing)

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: :( but I was tasked to do the routing on config.php

Comment: btw, these routings are done on a package. ex. laravel/packages/samplePackage/nhr/config/config.php <-- this is where I place the routes, using the syntax above. was just 'tasked' to do this by the lead programmer, -- he does his routes through config.php --> and are running . Don't know why it's not running for me.